# how to add parameters to a custom command vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, parameters

Have a Function which is converting string to hex. its fine working with a textbox and a button. But in my project theres a console form and theres a richtext box as output and a textbox as inputbox. users have to type commands and press enter to execute orders.

i'm trying to make it like : hex "string"
here is current state of inputbox code:

```
Private Sub consoleinputbox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles consoleinputbox.KeyDown
    Dim Command As String = consoleinputbox.Text
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Output(Command)
        CallCommand(Command)

    End If
End Sub
```

output function is appending text to richtextbox. CallCommand function is like this:

```
    Public Function CallCommand(s As String) 'seperate commands as func.
    Dim ss As String = s.ToLower()
    ss = ss.Trim
    Select Case ss
        Case "cls"
            GetRtb.rtb.Clear()
        Case "help cls"
            GetRtb.rtb.AppendText("Obviusly clear your console screen..." & vbCrLf)
            Return True
        Case "ping"
            GetRtb.rtb.AppendText("insufficient parameters. type help ping for more information..." & vbCrLf)
            Return True
        Case "help ping"
            GetRtb.rtb.AppendText("usage: ping [hostname or ip]" & vbCrLf)
            Return True
        Case "help"
            GetRtb.rtb.AppendText("Avaliable commands:" & vbCrLf)
            GetRtb.rtb.AppendText(avaliablecommands(s))
            Return True
        Case Else
            GetRtb.rtb.AppendText("Bad command or filename..." & vbCrLf)
            Return False
    End Select
End Function
```

how can i check consoleinputbox.text if it have spaces and 
if there is spaces how can i seperate first word as command and rest as parameters?
as you can see like "ping www.me.com" or "hex asdasd"
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

i think this is solved problem but if i need more parameters i have to make more functions like Callcommand2 etc...
inputbox code:

```
    Private Sub consoleinputbox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles consoleinputbox.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        e.SuppressKeyPress = True
        Dim text As String = consoleinputbox.Text
        Dim Command As String()
        Command = text.Split(" ")
        If Command.Length = 1 Then
            text.Trim()
            Output(text)
            CallCommand(Command(0))
        ElseIf Command.Length = 2 Then
            Output(text)
            CallCommand1(Command(0), Command(1))
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

and rest of module;

```
    Public Sub Output(s As String)
    If s <> "" Then
        GetRtb.rtb.AppendText(s & vbCrLf)
        GetTb.tb.Clear()
        GetTb.tb.Focus()
    End If
End Sub

Public Function CallCommand(c1 As String)
    c1.ToLower()
    Select Case c1
        Case "cls"
            GetRtb.rtb.Clear()
        Case "help"
            Output("Avaliable Commands")
            Call avaliablecommands()
        Case "hex"
            Output("insufficent parameters. use: help hex")
        Case "ascii"
            Output("insufficent parameters. use: help ascii")
        Case Else
            Output("Bad command or filename...")
    End Select
    Return True
End Function
Public Function CallCommand1(c1 As String, p2 As String)
    c1.ToLower()
    p2.ToLower()
    Select Case c1
        Case "help"
            help_par(p2)
        Case "hex"
            hex_par(p2)
        Case "ascii"
            ascii_par(p2)
    End Select
    Return True
End Function
Function help_par(p As String)
    Select Case p
        Case "ping"
            Output("usage: ping [hostname or ip]")
        Case "cls"
            Output("obviusly clears you console...")
        Case "hex"
            Output("converts string to hexcimal code. usage: hex <string>")
        Case "ascii"
            Output("converts hexcimal code to string. usage: ascii <hexcode>")
    End Select
    Return True
End Function
Function hex_par(p As String)
    Dim sth As String = StringToHex(p)
    Output(sth)
    Return True
End Function
Function ascii_par(p As String)
    Dim tostring As String = HexToString(p)
    Output(tostring)
    Return True
End Function
Public Sub avaliablecommands()
    Output("help, cls, ping, hex, ascii")
End Sub
```

End Module

im very very new to programming so please need ideas.